# Trouble selecting specific property values from this object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm currently struggling to do something rather straightforward. I simply want to print out specific key values for every object in this array. I'd appreciate any pointers!

```js
var countries = [

  {
    'country name': 'Australia',
    'national emblem': 'blue red white',
    'hemisphere': 'southern',
    'population': 24130000
  },
  {
    'country name': 'United States',
    'national emblem': 'blue red white',
    'hemisphere': 'northern',
    'population': 323000000
  },
  {
    'country name': 'Uzbekistan',
    'national emblem': 'blue green red white',
    'hemisphere': 'northern',
    'population': 31850000
  }

];


function getCountryprops(countries){
  
  for(var oneCountry in countries){
    for(var propName in oneCountry){
      console.log(oneCountry[propName]['country name'], oneCountry[propName]['population']);
    }
  }
}
```

So I want to ultimately print out [['Australia', 24130000],['United States', 323000000],['Uzbekistan', 31850000]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) on the `countries` array the `oneCountry` variable is the index of the current country. To get the country, you need to use the brackets notation on the `countries` array:

```js
var countries = [{"country name":"Australia","national emblem":"blue red white","hemisphere":"southern","population":24130000},{"country name":"United States","national emblem":"blue red white","hemisphere":"northern","population":323000000},{"country name":"Uzbekistan","national emblem":"blue green red white","hemisphere":"northern","population":31850000}];

function getCountryprops(countries){
  for(var oneCountry in countries){
    console.log(countries[oneCountry]['country name'], countries[oneCountry]['population']);
  }
}

getCountryprops(countries);
```

Another option is to use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to get the country's value directly:

```js
var countries = [{"country name":"Australia","national emblem":"blue red white","hemisphere":"southern","population":24130000},{"country name":"United States","national emblem":"blue red white","hemisphere":"northern","population":323000000},{"country name":"Uzbekistan","national emblem":"blue green red white","hemisphere":"northern","population":31850000}];

function getCountryprops(countries){
  for(var oneCountry of countries){
    console.log(oneCountry['country name'], oneCountry['population']);
  }
}

getCountryprops(countries);
```